# Using a page item as its value in LIKE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to get all the titles from a table in an interactive report where a certain word is found within another column of that table (article column). The word would be input through a text field called "TEXT". This is what I have in the interactive report region source:

```
SELECT title as "Word found in" 
FROM articles 
WHERE article like '% :TEXT %'
```

I'm not sure how to deal with the "TEXT" text field, this worked for equal (as in WHERE something =: TEXT)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT title as "Word found in" 
FROM articles 
WHERE instr(TEXT, article)>0;
```

I'm not at all sure what you're doing here, but this may work for you.

Comment: Gives me ORA-00904: "TEXT": invalid identifier. What part of what I'm trying to do is unclear? :p

Comment: You cannot use '%:bind_variable%'  in a statement that way.  The double quotes forces it to "%:TEXT%" -- not the value of the variable you wanted.  Your final solution is correct.  The :TEXT is what confused me.